# mssql filter by date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a little query that builds a count of rows per month&year, to mimic the behavior you'd see in google analytics.

this is my query:

```
USE MyDatabase;

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Rows,
    DATENAME(mm, OpenDate) AS Month,
    DATENAME(yyyy, OpenDate) AS Year
FROM MyTable
WHERE Priority = 1
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, OpenDate), DATENAME(yyyy, OpenDate)
ORDER BY Year, Month DESC;
```

I'm unclear as to how I'd apply a date range filter in this query.

1. Should I use `HAVING` or `WHERE`?
2. Do I need to use a fully formed datetime string for my vars? or do I filter by year and months separately since I've got those columns?

Comment: `WHERE OpenDate >= @Date1 and OpenDate <= @Date2`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: Since he's using a GROUP BY, I would expect: `HAVING OpenDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2` would work.

Comment: thanks, both of you. but should I put in a full datetime string for the `date1` and `date2` vars?

Comment: @SQLHound Yes, but `HAVING` is typically for aggregation usage, while it can be used here a `WHERE` clause makes more sense.

Comment: I hate to trouble either of you, but for the quality of the question's sake, could you post answers so i can upvote and select something?

Comment: Why do people post so many answers in comments? I don't get it. I would like to understand this; can someone explain?

Comment: @PittsburghDBA I tend to do it when the answer is very obvious and very simple to me.  I assume that I've misunderstood something.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA I commented because I didn't have time to write a full answer to the question.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for explaining. I always wondered. Sometimes the answers are excellent, and the commenter gets zero credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bluefeet says, this should work generally speaking:

```
WHERE OpenDate >= @Date1 and OpenDate <= @Date2
```

> Should I use HAVING or WHERE?

WHERE.

HAVING is for filtering out *after* the grouping and aggregation, so a good rule of thumb is that you only use it when you need to refer to the aggregate function like `HAVING COUNT(*) > 10` or similar.  Also, remember that every field in the HAVING clause must also be in the GROUP BY or an aggregate.  It would work here, but it's better logic to avoid HAVING unless you know you need it.  Generally, the earlier you can filter things out of your data set, the faster it will process, and WHERE processes before GROUP BY.

> Do I need to use a fully formed datetime string for my vars? or do I filter by year and months separately since I've got those columns?

It's typically easiest to make fully formed dates or datetimes.  You're going to cross year boundaries at some point, and those can be a huge pain if you don't.  What if you want November of 2014 through January of 2015?  Or May 2013 to May 2015?

---

The only thing you need to decide is if or how you aggregate fractional months.  So, does the application allow the user to say they want June 23, 2014 to July 13, 2014?

If they do, do you return that, or do you return everything in June and July and ignore the fact that they picked a specific date?

If it's the former, then @bluefeet's answer is fine:

```
WHERE OpenDate >= @Date1 and OpenDate <= @Date2
```

If not, then you might need to modify your date criteria.  Usually, you'll want to say:

```
WHERE OpenDate >= {First Date Of Date1's Month}
    AND OpenDate < {First Date of Month After Date2 Month}
```

So if you want from June 23, 2014 to January 13, 2015 would look like:

```
WHERE OpenDate >= '2014-06-01' 
    AND OpenDate < '2015-01-01'
```

Doing it like this means you don't have to worry about how many days are in a month.  You can usually handle the date math in your application before you even submit it to the query engine, but it can be done in SQL with CAST(), YEAR(), MONTH(), and DATEADD().

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could also cast your datetime field (OpenDate) to date and do something like this:

```
USE MyDatabase;

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
    ,@EndDate DATE

SET @StartDate = '2015-05-01'
SET @EndDate = '2015-05-30'

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows
        ,DATENAME(mm, OpenDate) AS Month
        ,DATENAME(yyyy, OpenDate) AS Year
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Priority = 1
        AND CAST(OpenDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate
            AND @EndDate
    GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, OpenDate)
            ,DATENAME(yyyy, OpenDate)
    ORDER BY Year,Month DESC;
END
```

**WHERE VS HAVING?**

`WHERE` clause restricts data before the aggregation is performed, whereas `HAVING` clause restricts data after the aggregation is performed.

Using `WHERE` clause is always better because there is no need to make the computer calculate aggregations and then filter them out.